# Mocked method, but it calls the actual one

Tags: java, json, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to mock a call to the getJSONFile() that returns someJson object from a json file.

```
public class NameClass{
    public String getValues() throws Exception 
            {
                HelpingClass e=new HelpingClass();
                String name=" ";
                String age=" "; 
                String gender=" ";
                JSONObject json= e.getJSONFile();
                json.getString("name");
                json.getString("age");
                json.getString("gender");
                System.out.println("Request received is "+json);
                ------ I have some other logic with JSON received and return string...

    }
}
```

This is my getJSONFile()

```
public class HelpingClass{
     public JSONObject getJSONFile() throws Exception
        {
            System.out.println("Getting JSON file");
            File f = new File("src/main/resources/input.json");
            JSONObject json ;
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
            String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is);
            json=new JSONObject(jsonTxt);
            return json;
        }
}
```

This is my test case

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestValues {

    @InjectMocks NameClass names;
    @Mock HelpingClass help;
    @Test
    public void testgetValues() throws Exception
    {
        //I am expecting this output
        JSONObject addValues=new JSONObject();
        addValues.put("name", "Rahul");
        addValues.put("age", "30");
        addValues.put("gender","male");
        //this is what i am returning when help.getJSONFile is called
        JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
        json.put("name", "Rahul");
        json.put("age", "30");
        json.put("gender", "male");
        //Mocking this call and returning my json
        Mockito.when(help.getJSONFile()).thenReturn(json);
        String s=names.getValues();
        Assert.assertEquals(addValues.toString(),s);
    }
}
```

Now instead of returning the created json it is returning me my JSON in the file like name is Rohit age is 28 and gender is male.

Why is this mocking not working? Technically it should call mocked method and return values in json object of JSONObject class i.e. Rahul, 30 years and male.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You dont seem to use HElpingClass in that method.. you usse Ex e=new Ex();.. to get the json

Comment: what is returned by names.getValues()?

Comment: No, I am sorry, that was typo.. It is actually helping class. i have edited code pls check now

Comment: After getting this json i am supposed to search for the fileds in an excel and return that as a string. That is all secondary, my question is when i am mocking the input and returning it in mocked call why is it still getting me the actual input from input.json

Comment: I think it is normal. Because no matter what you are always calling the input.json file.

Why not give a filename as parameter in getJSONFile() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well @InjectMocks wont work if you are instantiating the HelperClass inside of the method.

You would have to make it an instance variable or use a getter which you would then mock:

```
public class NameClass{

  public String getValues() throws Exception 
  {
            HelpingClass e= getHelpingClass();
            ....
  }

  HelpingClass getHelpingClass(){
      return new HelpingClass();
  }
}
```

and in your test use @Spy like following:

```
public class TestValues {

    @InjectMocks 
    @Spy
    NameClass names;
    @Mock HelpingClass help;
    @Test
    public void testgetValues() throws Exception
    {
        doReturn(help).when(names).getHelpingClass();
        Mockito.when(help.getJSONFile()).thenReturn(json);
        ...
     }
   }
```

Comment: That's exactly it. Mockito has no chance of injecting a mock this way. See http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.17/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html for documentation on how `@InjectMocks` works. Especially the note that "*If any of the following strategy fail, then Mockito won't report failure; i.e. you will have to provide dependencies yourself.*"

Comment: Thank You, it is getting me the values from json input i am asking it to return. But now i have a File file=new File(s). Where s is the file in which the content is to be searched but this is not happening. It throws me null win this line. Do i have any way to mock new File(s) so that it can create my new excel file s in which it has to search